# Any other dialog boxes like MessageBox in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I was bored using the Default MessageBox of windows phone. I downloaded Phone Toolkit to try something new UI for MessageBox. But that also same like Normal Message Box UI.

Is any other Dialog Boxes for Windows Phone like android has or iOS has ?

Answer (score 0):

A `MessageBox` is a specific type of control which is consistent throughout the phone. If you want a different look to it then you can create your own control which, for example, uses a [Popup control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/04/18/playing-with-the-popup-control.aspx) as the base but acts in the same way as the MessageBox. You could also modify the source of the MessageBox you got from the toolkit to change the appearance instead of creating the control from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand that default message box provided by sdk wont look fancy when your app goes live. So i can suggest you this control:

> MessagePrompt from coding4fun toolkit.

You can get the control from [codeplex open source](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) and download and add the reference to your app. If you need to know about them, tutorials are at [geekchamp website](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/12-wp7-coding4fun-toolkit-in-depth-articles-covering-all-controls) and also about in depth about [message prompt is here.](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/coding4fun-wp7-message-prompt-in-depth)

Tell me if this is intended or not.

Comment: sure. let me try this